# Correct handling of background calls in jersey

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have to do some background calls to a web service within a web application. The response of the call is not really time-critical and barely interesting for me. It changes only in rare cases, where I will react to it by throwing a exception, or logging the failure or something. 
My conrete question now refers to the correct handling of such asynch calls in Jersey Client 2.

Option 1 uses the async calls from jersey, but then starts a thread for each response.
Option 2 would immediatly start a thread and use jersey from inside this thread.

Generally which option would be more adviseable?

Option 1

```
private static final  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
```

--

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("somehost").path("somepath");

final AsyncInvoker asyncInvoker = target.request().async();

final Future<Response> responseFuture = asyncInvoker.post(Entity.json(myjsonobject));
executorService.execute(new Worker(responseFuture));
```

-- Worker Thread

```
  public class Worker implements Runnable {

     private Future<Response> futureResponse;

     public Worker(Future<Response> futureResponse){
         this.futureResponse = futureResponse;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
          final Response response = futureResponse.get();
          if(response.getStatus() == 500)
             doSomething();
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
 }
```

Option 2

```
private static final  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
```

--

```
   executorService.execute(new Worker());
```

-- Worker Thread

```
  public class Worker implements Runnable {

     public Worker(){
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
             Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
             WebTarget target = client.target("somehost").path("somepath");
             ClientResponse response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(myjsonobject), ClientResponse.class);
             if(response.getStatus() == 500) {
                  doSomething();
             }
          } catch(Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to implement a "non-blocking" `Future.get()` (with another thread), you can simply make use of the [`InvocationCallback`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/InvocationCallback.html), passing an instance to the `get` method. For example

```
Future<Response> future = target.request().async().get(new InvocationCallback<Response>(){
    @Override
    public void completed(Response response) {
        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
        client.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable throwable) { /** Log exception **/ }
});
```

See more at [Asynchronous Client Callbacks](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10419)